# stringByExpandingTildeinPath is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift2

I am getting the following error in Swift 2 after converting my project:

```
stringByExpandingTildeinPath is unavailable: use stringByExpandingTildeinPath on NSString instead
```

This is the code I'm using to share with whatsapp in Swift 1.2, the error at line 3:

```
                let filename = "myimage.wai"
                let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, false)[0] as NSString
                let destinationPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/" + filename).stringByExpandingTildeInPath
```

Comment: Do not build your path that way. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)` instead of `stringByAppendingString("/" + filename)`.

Comment: BTW - is that really the exact error message? It's really showing the function name in all lowercase like that?

Comment: @rmaddy, Thanks I've update it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you ask for it to not expand the `~` then expend it by yourself? Much simpler to let the API handle it by itself:

```
let filename = "myimage.wai"
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let destinationPath = documentsPath + "/" + filename
```

Comment: Don't manually build paths like this. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent`.

Comment: Why is that ? any alternative way ?

Comment: Unfortunately `stringByAppendingPathComponent` is no longer available on Swift 2.0. Apple wants everyone to use `NSURL` instead. And `NSURL` is really long-winded.

Comment: `NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent` is not deprecated.